# How to know a received email is reply or no in outlook?

Tags: c#, outlook

I am working on a task that I need to know if a received email is replying or no (outlook) by c#.

To do this I found a solution and it is checking `Re` in `subject` but some times maybe some users change `subject` in this scenario my code would be failed.
My current code is this, but I am looking for better solution.

```
foreach (MailItem item in mailItems)
{
    if (item.Subject.Contains("Re"))
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: A bit better solution `StartsWith("Re:")`

Comment: What if some one sends me "Re:Invent 2018 aws ..."?

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov thank you . I think that question would be help.